# mount -a asks for password with root user

Tags: mount, root

I have set up the cron job at reboot like

```
 @reboot sleep 20;mount -a
```

BUt i have received he email that it asks for password

how can i supply password with mount

Comment: can you give us a little more info from the email - what is the error reported ?

Comment: You'll need to add more detail to your question, preferably the contents of /etc/fstab and the message you're seeing in the email. As it is now your question isn't answerable and will probably be closed.

Comment: Btw, you may want to put the script in /etc/rc.local or /etc/rcS.d/, which should grant to be run quite after all other stuff.

Comment: Oh boy, don't do that. Use one of the saner ways, like init scripts, backgrounded mounts in case of NFS or autofs/automount.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean with CIFS, then look at the `user`, `password` and `credentials` mount options. See the `mount.cifs(8)` man page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

*mount -a* it's a "Mount All Filesystem", so you need root privileges. Just install the cronjob with

```
crontab -e
```

while logged in as root, or edit */etc/crontab* and modify the entry like:

```
0 * * * * @reboot root /bin/mount -a
```

Comment: while loogged as root , i typed crontab -e ND THEN   @REBOOT SLEEP 20; mount -a . then i receievc the email which has only one line "password:" or wait a minute--> i think may be that mail was from other file which i put in /etc/init.d/after.local which also contain mount -a and that was not root user. Looks like problem is solved

Comment: You wouldn't get a password prompt if `mount` is run from the wrong uid. Just something like "only root can do that".

Comment: @al mmm ... you're right. Never notice that.

Comment: u r right , i also get the passowrd prompt on next reboot